# how to delete duplicate lines in a file in Python

Tags: python, file, line

I have a file with duplicate lines. What I want is to delete one duplicate to have a file with unique lines. But i get an error **output.writelines(uniquelines(filelines))
TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings** 
I have searched the same issues but i still don-t understand what is wrong.
My code:

```
def uniquelines(lineslist):
    unique = {}
    result = []
    for item in lineslist:
        if item.strip() in unique: continue
        unique[item.strip()] = 1
        result.append(item)
    return result
file1 = codecs.open('organizations.txt','r+','cp1251')
filelines = file1.readlines()
file1.close()
output = open("wordlist_unique.txt","w")
output.writelines(uniquelines(filelines))
output.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code uses different open: `codecs.open` when it reads, `open` when it writes.

`readlines` of file object created using `codecs.open` returns list of unicode strings. While `writelines` of file objects create using `open` expect a sequence of (bytes) strings.

Replace following lines:

```
output = open("wordlist_unique.txt","w")
output.writelines(uniquelines(filelines))
output.close()
```

with:

```
output = codecs.open("wordlist_unique.txt", "w", "cp1251")
output.writelines(uniquelines(filelines))
output.close()
```

or preferably (using `with` statement):

```
with codecs.open("wordlist_unique.txt", "w", "cp1251") as output:
    output.writelines(uniquelines(filelines))
```

Answer (score 1):

i wouldn't bother encoding or decoding at all .. open with simply`open('organizations'txt', 'rb')` as well as `open('wordlist_unique.txt', 'wb')` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have the lines in order afterwards, I suggest you to put the strings in a set. `set(linelist)`. The lineorder would be screwed up but the duplicates would be gone.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather common in python to remove duplicate objects from a sequence using a set.  The only downside to using set is you lose order (the same way you loose order in dictionary keys, in fact its the same *exact* reason, but that's not important.)  If order in your files matters, you can use the keys of an OrderedDict (standard library as of... 2.7 I think) to act as a psudo-set, and remove duplicate strings from a sequence of strings.  If order does not matter, use `set()` instead of `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys()`.  Using the file modes 'rb' (read binary) and 'wb' (write binary), you stop having to worry about encoding - Python will just treat them as bytes.  This uses a context manager syntax introduced later than 2.5, so you may need to adjust with context lib as-needed if this is a syntax error for you.

```
import collections

with open(infile, 'rb') as inf, open(outfile, 'wb') as outf:
    outf.writelines(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(inf))
```

Comment: You don't need `readlines()`: iterating file objects yields lines. Also, you don't need `keys()`: iterating dictionary yields keys.

Comment: Consider add a brief description to clarify why your answer is useful. It's not enough with just the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello a got other solve:

For this file:

```
01 WLXB64US
01 WLXB64US
02 WLWB64US
02 WLWB64US
03 WLXB67US
03 WLXB67US
04 WLWB67US
04 WLWB67US
05 WLXB93US
05 WLXB93US
06 WLWB93US
06 WLWB93US
```

Solution:

```
def deleteDuplicate():
    try:
        f = open('file.txt','r')
        lstResul = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        datos = []
        for lstRspn in lstResul:
            datos.append(lstRspn)
        lstSize = len(datos)
        i = 0
        f = open('file.txt','w')
        while i < lstSize:
            if i == 0:
                f.writelines(datos[i])
            else:
                if (str(datos[i-1].strip())).replace(' ','') == (str(datos[i].strip())).replace(' ',''):
                    print('next...')
                else:
                    f.writelines(datos[i])
            i = i + 1

    except Exception as err:
```